# How to share the google android backup between applications?

Tags: android, backup

I've implemented [Android backup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) for my paid-application. I want to build an ad-supported version of the same app, and since they are using the same data I'd prefer to share the android backup between these two apps. How should I do?

Comment: Why do you need to share between the apps? Consider what would happen if a user has both installed (something is going to get overwritten).  I my application I have a feature that can automatically import the data from the old application (ad supported) to the new (paid) application.  This way the backup works correctly and the user can access all their old data

Comment: The app is mostly the same; the only different thing is that one is paid, and the other shows ads. Therefore it makes sense that the user data can be viewed and modified by both apps. (I may add that the data is used only when the apps is visible, therefore there is also no risk of concurrent access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

The refined question is whether it is possible to share the application backups on Google's servers.

My Answer: AFAIK it is not possible because Google will store the backups per package name, which must be unique per application.

**Original Answer**

I'm still not sure why you want to access the *same* data from both apps. Yes I understanding the upgrade path, but why not just copy the data over when the user gets the ad free one?

Anyway, your implementation of the BackupProvider will have to be responsible for managing the shared data.  Now since you will have 2 versions of the provider (free + paid) they need to ensure they don't overwrite each other in the shared location (like the sdcard).

But even if you follow this approach Google is still going to maintain 2 separate copies of your users data, one per application (AFAIK this is determined by the package name of the app which must be unique)

Comment: Actually what I want it's the other way around. I want Google to mantain 1 copy of my user data that is shared between the apps. Is that possible?

Comment: @michelemarcon not that I know of.